# Repeats across subject and Item with high percentage of single repeat data

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set, with a little over 300 subjects. This is an observational study, so randomization didn't happen. I want to compare 2 methods. about 200 subjects were under method 1 and rest were under method 2. But two methods are not mutually exclusive, means some subjects are in both methods(though the percentage of this type of subject is very low), also some subjects are repeated under each method. So, there are 3 types of subject.
1. Observed only once. (this is most common)
2. Observed more than once, but only under one method.
3. Observed more than once, but under both method(for example, subject A was 4 times observed under method 1 and 2 times under method 2)

what statistical model or testing procedure I should use, I tried, mixed effect model, but expectedly it didn't work, because too many random effects and too many subjects have only one response.

Comment: What are the proportions of the 3 types overall

Comment: @RobertLong ,type1=83.95%, type 2=8.96%,type 3=7.5%.

Comment: Please can you be more specific about what model you tried to fit ?

Comment: I have tried to fit a Linear mixed effect model.

Comment: Please be more specific!!!!!  What exactly was the model formula and what exactly was the error ????

Comment: @RobertLong response(weight)=fixed intercept+Fixed slope(Method)+ Subject specific Random Intercept. First I wanted to see if the simple mixed effect model works. Then I would have used more complex mixed effect model (with possibly random slope and more)